# dompdf - how to auto trigger print dialog in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, dompdf

I want print dialog to be open after PDF is rendered in browser which is working fine in firefox by adding JavaScript mentioned [here](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/713#issuecomment-24119287) but it is not working in chrome.

I have tried to add onload event and setTimeout function still it's not working.

**These scripts are working in firefox but not in chrome:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
    this.window.print();
    }
</script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
        setTimeout(function() {
            this.window.print();
        }, 3000);
    }
</script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() { this.window.print(); }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked with JavaScript for PDF. I believe `window` is a browser object and not available in all PDF readers. Try `this.print()` (`this` at the root level being the Doc object). You can check for support in your script or use try/catch to enable better cross-reader compatibility.

Here's one way to do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Javascript test</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>This document will trigger a print dialog.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        this.print();
    }
    catch(e) {
        window.onload = window.print;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript API implemented by the various browsers may or may not support the full API as documented by Adobe in the [JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf). I have so far been unable to find a reference for other PDF viewers (such as the one bundled with Chrome).

After some testing it does seem that there is limited support by the web browsers when a PDF is rendered stand-alone (i.e. within the browser chrome) versus in a web environment (i.e. in an iframe).

Also note that Dompdf does not support embedding JavaScript into the PDF by default so you'll have to enable it in the Dompdf settings.

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

$options = new Options();
$options->set('isJavascriptEnabled', true);
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
```

Comment: Same result, working in firefox but not in chrome :(

Comment: Might be a Chrome-specific security restriction. I'd have to do more research before I could say for sure.

Comment: I think print() method for dompdf is might not be compatible for Chrome, Edge and Opera browser (manual ctrl+p is working fine) and the funny thing is in firefox it triggers print dialog with just script tag `<script type="text/javascript"> </script>`  strange.

Comment: Just FYI it's not a Dompdf function but a general function supported by the reader. The reference I've used is the "JavaScript™ for Acrobat® API Reference" (link added to answer). I don't know if there's a similar document for the reader implemented in Chrome (I couldn't find one after a quick search). I did a quick test and this does seem to work OK in Chrome. I updated the example in the answer with a full document.

Comment: 'isJavascriptEnabled' is already set to 'true' still not working in chrome.

Comment: ah ha ha ... so I did some more testing and this really only seems to work if the PDF is embedded into some kind of iframe. I'd have to do more research (which I'm not able to do now) to determine what's happening. It seems like JS support is tied somewhat to the rendering environment (embedded in a web page vs stand-alone in the browser chrome).

Comment: Got you! Can you please update/fix this in your next version (0.8.6)? Till then I will use manual (ctrl+p) in chrome :p

Answer (score 0):

Opening a PDF (or any URL) in a new tab allows for (optionally) triggering the print dialog via the following function.

```html
/**
 * Opens a URL in a new tab. Optionally triggers the print dialog after the window has loaded.
 */
function openInNewTab(url: string, triggerPrintDialog: boolean = false): void {
    if (url !== "") {
        const newTabWindow = window.open(url, "_blank");
        if (newTabWindow !== null) {
            if (triggerPrintDialog) {
                newTabWindow.onload = newTabWindow.print;
            }
            newTabWindow.focus();
        }
        else {
            window.alert("openInNewTab() blocked by browser.");
        }
    }
}
```